# Can't access SQLite database on IIS

Tags: perl, sqlite, iis

Okay I've been trying to do this for hours and it just won't work. I have a simple Perl script that is trying to open a database:

```
my $db;
my $cgi = new CGI;
$db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db") or do
{
    print $cgi->header("text/plain", "500 Internal Server Error");
    print "Can't connect to database.";
};
```

The script works fine when run from the command line, but it refuses to work on IIS. I put both the script and database into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test and changed the whole test directory security to have all permission to Everyone. It still won't work. I don't know how to get it to access the file.

Comment: Have you checked whether your current working directory is also `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test`? How about full-specifying the path to the file in the `connect`? Does `dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:` work? What is in `$DBI::errstr`? Do you have `DBD::SQLite` installed?

Comment: errstr="unable to open database file", yes SQLite is installed since the script can be run from the command line, and yes I tried changing it to the full path, same behavior. Using :memory: makes the connect line work but then if I try to prepare it says "Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value"

Comment: Do you mean it fails if you `prepare` a statement and then call `execute` on the statement handle then it fails? That implies that your SQL syntax is wrong, but it's probably nothing to do with this problem. Are you expecting `test.db` to already exist? What happens if you `open my $fh, '<', 'test.db' or die $!`?

Comment: You should explicity add `Full control` capability of the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test` folder to the `IUSR` account (which is the account that runs IIS) and the `IIS_IUSRS` group. Also, if you have an *existing* `test.db` then you should delete it as its permissions may be different from that of the folder.

Comment: [This item may be useful](https://support.gearhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200342205-How-to-give-write-access-to-files-for-IUSR)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours finally managed to make it work by replacing `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.db` with `/inetpub/wwwroot/test/test.db`.

Sigh. No idea why.

Comment: If you had backslashes in a *double quoted* string then they will vanish. Double them up or, better, use single quotes. It's best to check that a non-trivial string contains what you think it does by printing it before you use it. You should also put the drive letter back. Try `my $dbname = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.db'; my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbname");`